# Updating static array with dynamic content from database in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to implement TimelineTableViewCell (https://github.com/kf99916/TimelineTableViewCell/blob/master/TimelineTableViewCellDemo/TimelineTableViewController.swift). It shows content in timeline.

For timeline posts, the demo has static content like this:

```
  // TimelinePoint, Timeline back color, title, description, lineInfo, thumbnail, illustration
 let data:[Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]] = [0:[
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.black, "12:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", nil, nil, "Sun"),
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.clear, "19:00", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", nil, nil, "Moon")
    ], 1:[
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "08:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "09:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "30 mins", nil, "Sun")]]
```

It is working fine with static content.

Now, I am trying to change those static content with content from database in tableview. I am bit confused how to declare that data array and later on append the data to it.

My get data function looks like this:

```
          {
     dataHelper.getConditionsData { (data1) in
          for post in data1 {
             let post1 = post as! NSDictionary
             let headline = post1.value(forKey: "headline")
             let text1 = post1.value(forKey: "text")
             let t_date = post1.value("t_date")
      //how do i declare empty array at top and append these to data array?
   }
```

The way I am doing it is giving me data does not have append member.

Any help?
how do I declare empty double dimensional array for the tuples at top and append those to data from database?

edit: for the database, I am doing this.

```
   var i=0; 
   dataHelper.getConditionsData { (data1) in 
   for post in data1 
   { 
   let postA = post as! NSDictionary 
   let condition_text = postA.value(forKey: "condition_text") 
   let condition_date = postA.value(forKey: "condition_date") 
   self.data[i] = [ (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, condition_date as! 
   String,condition_text as! String , "60 mins", nil, "Sun") ] 
   i = i+1 
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The actual answer to the OP's question turned out to be:

You're not calling `reloadData()` after retrieving your data.

---

You would declare the `data` dictionary as:

```
var data:[Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]] =
    [Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]]()
```

(note: I put it on two lines for readability)

Then, when you want to add to the dictionary, you do something like this:

```
    data[0] = [
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "08:30", "This is the Start of a test.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "09:30", "This is the End of the test.", "30 mins", nil, "Sun")
    ]
```

substituting the "Strings" with your `headline`, `text1`, etc variables.

---

**Edit:** I cloned the *TimelineTableViewCell* project you referenced.

In `TimelineTableViewController.swift` in the included demo, I:

- created the empty `data` dictionary as I had shown
- commented out the `let data:` sample data
- added two example data elements in `viewDidLoad()`

So, it looks like this:

```
class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var data:[Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]] =
        [Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]]()

    // TimelinePoint, Timeline back color, title, description, lineInfo, thumbnail, illustration
    //    var data:[Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]] = [0:[
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.black, "12:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", nil, nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.black, "15:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", nil, nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(color: UIColor.green, filled: true), UIColor.green, "16:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "150 mins", "Apple", "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.clear, "19:00", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", nil, nil, "Moon")
    //        ], 1:[
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "08:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "09:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "30 mins", nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "10:00", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "90 mins", nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "11:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "12:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "30 mins", "Apple", "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "13:00", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "120 mins", "Apple", "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "15:00", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "150 mins", "Apple", "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "17:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "18:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "60 mins", nil, "Moon"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "19:30", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "30 mins", nil, "Moon"),
    //            (TimelinePoint(), backColor: UIColor.clear, "20:00", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", nil, nil, "Moon")
    //        ]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data[0] = [
            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "08:30", "This is the Start of a test.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "09:30", "This is the End of the test.", "30 mins", nil, "Sun")
        ]

        data[1] = [
            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "16:30", "This is the Start of another test.", "60 mins", nil, "Mon"),
            (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "17:30", "This is the End of the second test.", "30 mins", nil, "Mon")
        ]

        let timelineTableViewCellNib = UINib(nibName: "TimelineTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle(for: TimelineTableViewCell.self))
        self.tableView.register(timelineTableViewCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TimelineTableViewCell")
    }

    // didn't touch anything after here
```

Running the app now shows me two "Days" each with two entries:

[image]

If that's not what you are getting, then you are making some other mistake...

---

Comment: Thanks. But it almost my answer but some problems.
var i=0;
        dataHelper.getConditionsData { (data1) in
            for post in data1 {
                let postA = post as! NSDictionary
                let condition_text = postA.value(forKey: "condition_text")
                let condition_date = postA.value(forKey: "condition_date")
                self.data[i] = [
                    (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, condition_date as! String,condition_text as! String , "60 mins", nil, "Sun")
                ]
                i = i+1
            }
          
        }

Comment: Nothing is appearing. Plus I have my array like this
data[0] = [
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "08:30", "This is the Start of a test.", "60 mins", nil, "Sun"),
        (TimelinePoint(), UIColor.lightGray, "09:30", "This is the End of the test.", "30 mins", nil, "Sun")
    ]
so how can i feed in? thanks

Comment: Thanks. Static thing is working but when I replace the static things with dynamic things, nothing is appearing, empty table. I used breakpoint, the dictionary is filled with data from database correctly i.e database retrieval is working fine but filling into the array is not being done is the right way resulting into the emtpy table.thank you very much.

Comment: @TheGooooogle - How are you getting the data? Is it stored locally? Are you retrieving it from a server? Are you calling `reloadData()` after parsing / processing the data (on the main thread)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was not reloading the data. I have updated my original question to show how i am retrieving the data. Now the only problem is: each record is taken as a new element of the array if there is multiple records for same day. i.e I need to do this array[0]=(row1,row2) rather than array[0]=row1 and array[1]=row2. So can i do that inject into array any idea?

Comment: @TheGooooogle - "How do I parse my data?" is an entirely different issue from your original question. You should post that as a new question.